# If 8 (indistinguishable) blackboards are to be divided among 4 schools, how many divisions are possible if each school must receive 2 blackboards?

Tags: combinatorics

I attempted to come up with a solution. Please verify that it is correct or explain if there is anything wrong with it.

Solution: Since each school must receive exactly 2 blackboards, we draw the stars and bars diagram as ..|..|..|.. 
Here, N=8 and r=3. We use (N-1 choose r-1) since no school can receive zero chalkboards. Thus, there are (7 choose 2) = 21 different possible divisions.

Comment: If the blackboards are indistinguishable, and each school gets $2$, how can there be more than one division?  Check your stars and bars formula.

Comment: Isn't the answer pretty clearly 1?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really mean the formula, I meant the reasoning.

Comment: The question stresses that the blackboards were indistinguishable, so I thought that was an indication that I needed to use the formula as shown above.

Comment: If you subtract the fixed allocations (2 boards per school) you are left with 0 stars and 3 bars. Clearly $\binom{0+3}{3} = 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of stars and bars is off. First of all, with $4$ schools, you have $r=4$, and thus $r-1=3$, rather than $2$.

But, more pressingly, the updated formula $7 \choose 3$ would give you the number of ways to divvy up the $8$ boards among the $4$ schools where each school gets *at least one*.  But, the constraint is that each school must receive *exactly two*. Your formula, for example, would count 'solutions' where two schools get $3$ boards, and the other two schools get $1$ board each, but that violates the constraint that each should get $2$. In short, the formula just does not apply.

Indeed, just using common sense the anwer must of course be $1$: there is exactly one way to give $8$ (indistinguishable) boards to $4$ schools, each receiving exactly $2$

Comment: Thank you for explaining.